# The use of "'rat out on"

Tags: meaning

To leave or abandon.

Can this expression be used to indicate an ordinary instance of leaving or abandoning  like:

I rat out on the party after midnight.
 I rat out on the city before noon.

Or has this expression a specific meaning with a more restricted use?

Comment: Normally the expression 'to rat on' means to tell on someone.

Comment: So what would you make of this sentence: Joe ratted out on Sue when she was seven months pregnant.

Comment: I think it is quite clear what it means. I did say 'normally'. But 'to rat' essentially means to behave like a rat, and have no concern for those who depend on you.

Comment: Never heard that usage before. Only *rat on* for tattling and *ran out on* for abandonment.

Comment: I've heard "ratted out" and "ratted on" but never "ratted out on".

Comment: I found this http://examaxe.mobsea.co/idioms/index.php?w=rat%20out%20on%20(someone), which supports your given definition, but it's not clear who has compiled the list, nor could I find any evidence of this idiom in use.

Comment: It's more specific than just "to leave". *"I ratted out on the party after midnight"* isn't a good usage, but you might be able say *"At the party last night, I ratted out just before it was time to clean the mess up."*

Comment: Could " to slink off" be a synonym?

Comment: Josh, your examples are **totally and completely wrong**.  it's that simple. To "rat" means to tell on someone.  Your examples are utterly incorrect. Like if I said "I'm typing on a carrot."

Answer (score 1):

The example given by the OP is illuminating:

> *Joe ratted out on Sue when she was seven months pregnant.*

While I have not heard the idiom used in quote in quite that form, it would seem to derive from the phrase *[rats deserting a sinking ship](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/desert+a+sinking+ship)*.

In the offered example, the (assumed) father is running away from the mother when he finds the circumstances to be uncomfortable.

It is not ordinarily used to mean leaving in a non-pejorative manner. Being compared to a rat is almost always negative in English.

Comment: That example is, quite simply, **wrong**.  You can find many examples on the internet of sentences with words used in completely the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

The examples are utterly incorrect.

Rat does not mean "To abandon."

To find the meaning of a word, check in a dictionary.